# Send Customer Notification via API call

Tags: rest-api, email

I've been having some issues getting emails to send when inserting a CaseComment. I'm currently using the [nForce](https://github.com/kevinohara80/nforce/) npm module as my program is written for use with nodejs.

Some sample code

```
const casecoment = nforce.createSObject('CaseComment', {
    CommentBody: 'API-based nForce test for a comment',
    ParentId: cParentId,
    IsPublished,
});

org.insert({
    sobject: casecoment,
    oauth,
}, (err, resp) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Could post to case comment");
        console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
    }
    else {
        console.log('posting comment worked!');
    }
});
```

What I'm wondering is what else I may need to do in order to get emails for case updates to the contact sent out. I'm able to get emails as the case owner without any issues. On the CaseComment sObject page, I saw that "IsNotificationSelected" is a column I can read, but isn't something I can create as I just receive an error when adding it to my code above.

Is there a way to programmatically have the notification email sent out like the "Send Customer Notification" in the website interface?

Answer (score 0):

Look at your array, IsPublished isn't set to true, and as you point out neither is IsNotificationSelected ([API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_casecomment.htm))

```
{
  CommentBody: 'API-based nForce test for a comment',
  ParentId: cParentId,
  IsPublished: true
  IsNotificationSelected: true,
}
```

Lastly, you might migrate to [jsforce](https://jsforce.github.io/).